# Select / Insert using dates and union-vb

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, union

I am trying to use a single SQL command to do two selects I want to select related data and insert it in another table from another database, but it isn't working, I am new to this, can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
Try
    If CreateAccessDatabase("C:\Users\Utilizador.Utilizador-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Doc_Vendas_Cab.mdb") = True Then
        MsgBox("Database Created")
    Else
        MsgBox("Database Creation Failed")
    End If

    Dim Sql As String = "Select strCodSeccao,strAbrevTpDoc,strCodExercicio,intNumero " & _
         "From Mov_Venda_Cab where dtmdata between @d1 and @d2; Union" & _
         "Select Mov_Venda_Lin.Strcodartigo" & _
         "from Mov_Venda_Lin,Mov_Venda_Cab where Mov_Venda_Cab.intnumero=Mov_Venda_Lin.intnumero;"

    Dim data1, data2 As DateTime
    data1 = DateTime.Parse(txtData1.Text)
    data2 = DateTime.Parse(txtData2.Text)

    data2 = data2.AddMinutes(0)
    data2 = data2.AddHours(0)
    data2 = data2.AddSeconds(0)

    data1 = data1.AddMinutes(0)
    data1 = data1.AddHours(0)
    data1 = data1.AddSeconds(0)

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5 As String


    Using con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & txtserv.Text & ";" & "Initial Catalog=" & txtBD.Text & ";" & "User ID=" & txtuser.Text & ";" & "Password=" & txtPass.Text & "")
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", data1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", data2)
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim strCodSeccao = reader("strCodSeccao").ToString()
                    temp1 = reader.Item(x)
                    temp2 = reader.Item(x + 1)
                    temp3 = reader.Item(x + 2)
                    temp4 = reader.Item(x + 3)
                    temp5 = reader.Item(x + 4)

                    Dim Con2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Utilizador.Utilizador-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Doc_Vendas_Cab.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
                    Con2.Open()
                    Dim Ole2 As String = "Insert into Mov_Venda_Cab values('" & temp1 & "','" & temp2 & "','" & temp3 & "','" & temp4 & "','" & temp5 & "');"
                    Dim OledbCom2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Ole2, Con2)

                    Try
                        OledbCom2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Catch Ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(Ex)
                    End Try
                    Con2.Close()
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

Catch Ex As Exception
    MsgBox(Ex)
End Try
```

Comment: Please explain what _isn't working_. Error messages? Help us to help you

Comment: The connections `SQLCon` and `Conn` are never used.

Comment: Not part of the question, but you can use a select query in place of the VALUES clause for an insert, and thus avoid ever even bringing this to the client. That should _greatly_ increase performance here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: He transfers data between two different DBs.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Same connection string. But even if it were to different DB servers, SQL Server talks to itself: it will be far more efficient to use linked servers and send the info that way.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: He is transfering from SQL-Server (`con`) to Jet-Engine (`Con2`). The other two connections (`SQLCon`, `Conn`) are obsolete. But you are right, linking the two DBs would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT statement encloses all the values in single quotes. This will only work if the corresponding columns are all text columns (varchar, nvarchar etc.). Use command parameters instead:

```
Dim Ole2 As String = "Insert into Mov_Venda_Cab values(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5);"
Dim OledbCom2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Ole2, Con2)
OledbCom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", temp1)
OledbCom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", temp2)
OledbCom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", temp3)
OledbCom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", temp4)
OledbCom2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", temp5)
```

This will work for any column type.

---

Also your SELECT statement lists only four columns, but you are accessing five columns in the `reader`.

```
SELECT strCodSeccao, strAbrevTpDoc, strCodExercicio, intNumero FROM ...
```

---

Other things in your code are strange as well. Your are defining two connections that are never used later.

You are adding zero hours, minutes and seconds to a date (this will not change the date). If you want the date part of the date without the time part, use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property instead, which returns the date component of the `DateTime` structure:

```
data1 = DateTime.Parse(txtData1.Text).Date
```

You are using a variable `x` for constant values.

You are opening and closing `Con2` in the While-loop. Open it before the loop and close it after the loop. (You can do it with a `Using`-statement as for the other connection.)